# how to pass values with their labels on click event in angular4

Tags: html, angular, dom

I want to hide the li when clicking the plus button. here my data are passing  but li is not clearing .(my output is like when clicking the plus button the datas are move but still the li is there.i want to remove the li instance)
[image]
my html code is

```
 <div class="searchResult-Container">
     <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let stocks of products"
     [class.selected]="stocks === selectedStock"
     (click)="onSelected(stocks)">
      <div class="row searchItem" style="margin:0px;">
       <!--search item starts-->
     <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden">
   <label>Item</label>
     <span>{{stocks.ItemID}} </span>
       </div>
```

and my TS code is

```
    onSelected(IComboDetails: IComboDetails): void {
    this.selectedStock = IComboDetails;

}
```

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat actually I want to hide the li when clicking the plus button. here my data are passing when clicking but li is not passing

Comment: Is this displayed as a part of a modal or a popup?

Comment: change [class.selected]="stocks === selectedStock" to [hidden]="stocks === selectedStock"

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat its a popup

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat but adding 2nd item it will show same li

Comment: @BrockJames could you please update question what is your expected result? because looks like you want to do something different then you said previously

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to remove all items you click plus

```
   onSelected(comboDetails: IComboDetails): void {
      const index = this.products.indexOf(comboDetails);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.products.splice(index, 1);
      }  
   }
```

Comment: i found some error (prpperty index doesnot exist on the type IComboDetails)actually i am using angular4 with webapi in vs2015

Comment: Can you add screenshot?

Comment: @BrockJames And what is type of your products? is it IComboDetails[]?

Comment: yeah it is IComboDetails[]

Comment: but when i use like  this [hidden]="stocks === selectedStock"
 i got it but if the search item one or more is their  the last li of itemdetails are show

Comment: actually, i am new in angular

Comment: @BrockJames can you please add screenshot of error "prpperty index doesnot exist on the type IComboDetails"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198118/discussion-between-brock-james-and-volodymyr-bilyachat).